# Read Non Blocking error while using pxssh

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I am trying to do ssh on my machine using a python script using pxssh moudule. And i landed in

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pxssh.py", line 243, in login
    if not self.synch_original_prompt():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pxssh.py", line 134, in synch_original_prompt
    self.read_nonblocking(size=10000,timeout=1) # GAS: Clear out the cache before getting the prompt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 824, in read_nonblocking
    raise TIMEOUT ('Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().')
pexpect.TIME

OUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
```

After that i referred

> [Read Non Blocking error while using pxssh (ssh module for python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012665/read-non-blocking-error-while-using-pxssh-ssh-module-for-python)

And followed the second solution

> "I just added a self.sendline() and a time.sleep(0.5) right before the
>   first read_nonblocking() call within synch_original_prompt()"

After doing that my timeout error was solved but i am getting output same as the command that i am giving.I tried printing out child.before and child.after

```
print child.before
print child.after
```

output was

```
ls -l
<class 'pexpect.TIMEOUT'>
```

Here is my complete code

```
import pxssh

def send_command(child,cmd):
    child.send(cmd)
    child.prompt()
    print child.before
    print child.after

def connect(host,user,pwd):   
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    s.login(host,user,pwd,auto_prompt_reset=True)
    return s

def main():
    s = connect('127.0.0.1','root','*********')
    send_command(s, "ls -l")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are you sure you can connect using the given credentials using `ssh` from the command line?

Comment: @Pedro yeah...i could connect through the terminal. Problem is only while using pexpect